# Which API to use to edit a word document from C# on a headless server?

Tags: c#, ms-word

I would like to edit a MS Word document (`docx`) from a headless Windows server, e.g. set some text bold. Is that possible with C#? It will be part of a web application:

- user uploads document
- server modifies document (e.g. sets some text bold)
- users can download modified document

My question is to know **which API to use** to edit the Word document.

Comment: _Is that possible with C#_ - maybe, maybe not, but knowing that won't help you much. What's your real question?

Comment: Thanks @MikeW, I just edited the question accordingly

Comment: http://openxmldeveloper.org/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe checkout the following MSDN link, which details how to apply a style to a paragraph in a Word document using the OpenXML API:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc850838(v=office.15).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#sampleCode

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @paul-zahra 's comment, I will use [OpenXmlSDK](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-content/tree/master/en-us/OpenXMLCon).